# How to get proper UV mapping with an Ocean modifier?

Tags: modifiers, uv, texture-coordinates, ocean-simulation

I want to apply a gradient like texture on an ocean plane. Without the modifier, it works perfectly as shown below.

As soon as the Ocean modifier is applied with repetition on the X and Y axis, the UV Map is neither tiled nor applied to the whole surface.

I tried Object, Generated and UV without success.

How can I fix that?

Without modifier:

[image]

With Ocean modifier:

[image]

Modifier options:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use UV Project modifier after the Ocean modifier to project UVs from another object:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me with Blender 4.0 beta, Martynas solution didn't work (the UVproject modifier didn't work with the Ocean modifier). But the approach gave me an idea which was useful ^^ Thank you!

Adding an intermediary geometry is indeed the solution. With an additional plane, the UVmap of the plane is chosen as an input for the texture coordinates in the shader of the ocean.
And it works like a charm.

[image]

EDIT : Martynas solution DO work in Blender 3.6 at least.

Comment: I am glad that you found another acceptable solution, but I don't know what you are talking about regarding UV project modifier not working. It [works just fine as well.](https://imgur.com/HAqjTUC)

Comment: Well I must be super unlucky :/ I don't know why it doesn't work :  [screenshot here](https://ibb.co/sv4fDtB)

Comment: OK, that's weird. I am using version 3.6.1 Baybe you are using older version? May be a bug.

Comment: I'm on 4.0 beta. I just edited my answer to enable your solution

Comment: I thought it's pretty much the same with Material nodes and the modifier. Well the node solution is definitely not worse in any way, so at least that works.

Comment: Yep, I'm glad I have at least a working solution and 3.6 users, two solutions :)

Comment: It is weird though. Seems to work on 4.0 Alpha for me as well. No idea why.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using it correctly. No idea either

Comment: Just to check, did you use multiple repetitiond on X and Y for the ocean modifier?

Comment: Yes, I certainly did. I did open a file set up with 3.6 though, instead of making it all in 4.0, so that maybe why it worked. I will check it better when I get a spare minute just out of curiosity.